Error: Failed to Lookup View in Express.js (EJS), Can't Find My Template
I’m building a web application using Node.js and Express. I have set up routes and controllers for handling user dashboards, but I keep getting the error 'Failed to lookup view "user/user_dashboard" in views directory "./views" when trying to access the page. I’m not sure what I’m missing.
I've created two files server.js to start the server and app.js for the middleware. In addition I have user routes called user.js and a controller file called user.js aswell.
This is my folder structure:
src/ controllers/ user.js (Controller logic here) views/ user/ user_dashboard.ejs (The EJS file I’m trying to render) routes/ user.js (Route definitions) app.js server.js
Here are the key parts of my code:
app.js
      const express = require('express');
      const app = express();


      app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

      // Set the views directory
      app.set('views', './views');

      // Middleware for json
      app.use(express.json());



`Use routes`    

       const userRoutes = require('./routes/user.js');
       app.use('/user', userRoutes);  // puts user related routes under /user



       module.exports = app;  // Export the app setup


`server.js`

     const app = require('./app.js');  // Import the app setup from app.js
        const port = 3000;

        // Starts the server
        app.listen(port, () => {
          console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
        });


'routes/user.js'

     // src/routes/user.js
        const express = require('express');
        const router = express.Router();
        const userController = require('../controllers/user.js');

        // User-related routes
        router.get('/dashboard', userController.getDashboard);  // URL: /user/dashboard

        module.exports = router;


`controller/user.js`   

    exports.getDashboard = (req, res) => { 
            const userData = {};  // will fetch user dashboard data from database
            res.render('user/user_dashboard', { user: userData }); 
            //console.log('User dashboard data sent');
          };


`userdashboard.ejs`

     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <h1>Welcome to your Dashboard, username</h1>
        <p>Navbar with stuff</p>
        <p>Profile info</p>
        <p>Your borrowed items:</p>
        <ul>
    
            <li>items borrowed</li>
  
        </ul>
    
    </html>

I have verified that the file paths are correct.
I have tried detailing whole file paths instead of just "user_dashboard" for example. And adding file types like .ejs to the end of the file paths.
I have checked whether the program is reaching the controller file with console.log.
I've asked my peers in my group work for help and tried throwing my problem at various AIs, which keep giving me the same advice of "check the file paths are correct".
I expect when I navigated to "http://localhost:3000/user/dashboard" I am displayed with my "user_dashboard.ejs" file.

I've tried this exact setup and had no issues, the page rendered. Just for testing purposes clone my repo and try to run it.

Hi, thankyou for responding!! It turns out the issue was I needed to add a path.join() where I was setting the views directory and that worked. I'm not sure how it worked for you with the exact same setup. Specifically the whole line is app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

Glad it worked out for you. Normally, I also set my view like that, but I wanted to test and see if it would work with this setup and it did. It is unclear to me why it worked for me but not for you, though.
